# pdfptable header repeat when data in a different table increases in itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

In my project i need to create a pdfptable with two columns in itext.These two columns contain two different inner tables (Column 1 contains one inner table and column 2 contains one inner table). Now both of these inner tables have header rows set in them. My problem is that i need to repeat the header of column 1 inner table when data in column 2 inner table increases.
I have created all the table required. But could not find any good solution
I know its a strange requirement but please try to help if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this, is by using a table event. See [NestedTables3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/NestedTables3) and [nested_tables3.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/nested_tables3.pdf) for an example:

[image]

This is the code you need to achieve this:

```
class MyPdfPTableEvent implements PdfPTableEvent {

    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
    }

    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS]);
        for (int i = 1; i < widths[1].length; i++) {
            Rectangle position = new Rectangle(widths[1][i - 1], heights[1], widths[1][i], heights[2]);
            ct.setSimpleColumn(position);
            ct.addText(new Phrase("This inner table header will always be repeated"));
            try {
                ct.go();
            } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to declare this event to your table:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.setTableEvent(new MyPdfPTableEvent());
```

Of course: for this to work, you need to add an empty cell to provide sufficient space for the text you're adding in the table event.

Comment: Thank you! Mr. Bruno Lowagie, this example seems to address my problem. Will let you know if I solve my problem with this.

Comment: Thank you! Mr. Bruno Lowagie your example solved my problem.